# Flask template with two list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

for each row i what to add to  like this:

```
 <td>{{ dls[2] }}</td><td>{{ dls[4] }}</td>
```

in the next row i what to add

```
<td>{{ dls[8] }}</td><td>{{ dls[10] }}</td>
```

in the next row i what to add

```
<td>{{ dls[14] }}</td><td>{{ dls[16] }}</td>
```

etc

i total have 6 X more dls of table. but i just what to print 2,4,8,10,14,16... alway x+2 x+4

```
<table class="table table-striped">
{% for row in table %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ row[1]|truncate(100) }}</td>
 ///somthing like this/// --> <td>{{ dls[2] }}</td><td>{{ dls[4] }}</td> <--
    <td> <a href="{{ row[2] }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> download</button></a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

part of view.py

```
dls =  soup.find_all('td',{'align':'center'})


table = [[str(i + 1) if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 else i + 1,
    href[i] if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 else href[i],
    href2[i] if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 else href2[i]] for i in range(len(href))]
    #dls[i] if (i + 2) % 2 ==  0 else dls[i]] for i in range(len(href))]
return render_template('query.html', query=query,  table=table, dls=dls)
```

Comment: Jinja2 has loop steps. I think that's what you're looking for

Comment: I think it's only a part of the solution. I am beginner

Comment: its possibly best to extract from dls (dls[2] dls[4] ) and add new cols inside of table. (dls[2] dls[4] ) to dls[1] and dls2[1],  (dls[8] dls[10] ) to dls[2] and dls2[2], (dls[14] dls[16] ) to dls[3] and dls2[3]

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but you should be able to do `for i in range(0, 13, 6):` and use `(dls[i+2], dls[i+4])`,which gets positions 2,4,8,10,14,16

Comment: Ok but I want to put dls[i+2] in a[1] and dls[i+4] in b [1] for the first pass.... its need to be increments of 1..

Comment: You can toss in an `if i == 0` condition

Comment: `a=1
    for i in range(0,13,6):
      list2[a] = list1[i+2]
      list3[a] = list1[i+4]
      a=a+1`
I dont kown if its work by i think its what i want